# How to lock expanding/collapsing action programmatically?

Tags: android, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I would like to keep this layout on specific action:

[image: Initial layout]

Nowadays, I can collapse or expand this `CoordinatorLayout` by performing swipe on it. I want to block this behavior.

Comment: so i think you have to write your own `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.Behavior`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I assume your list is using a `RecyclerView`.

You can turn off nested scrolling on your `RecyclerView` which will disable the toolbar collapse:

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

You can lock the toolbar by clearing the scroll flags:

```
CollapsingToolbarLayout toolbar = findViewById(R.id.collapsingToolbar);  // or however you need to do it for your code
AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
params.setScrollFlags(0);  // clear all scroll flags
```

Comment: I would like to lock toolbar - the black part from expanding/collapsing action. It can be done by swipe/scroll on toolbar. I don't want it, so I'm looking for lock this behaviour

Comment: Btw works too if you want to keep toolbar collapsed:

appBar.setExpanded(false);
nestedScrollView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);